# Intellij IDEA 2019.2: Set the maven home directory "globally" for all projects

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, settings

Every time I clone a repo I have to manually set the maven home directory under `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Build Tools-> Maven-> Maven home directory` which is very annoying. I searched jetbrains forums and there is only an option to configure the IDE for FUTURE projects which under circumstances can never be a fact. Cloning a repo into idea projects is not creating a new project and therefore the global settings do not get triggered. How can I do this? Btw it not only applies to Maven home dir but also Code Style settings and many other more - see [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000079170-How-to-make-certain-settings-global-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have a feature to propagate any setting to all the existing projects. A request [is welcome](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA).

Comment: I have created [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221422)